# Reopen edited "Managing a project with an unfamilar programming language"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen, reopen-request

I've edited out the offending resource request in [Managing a project with an unfamilar programming language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/440856/131624). I don't see yet another good close reason. Any chance we can get this reopened before it ages out into oblivion?

Comment: I think the question is still way too broad to be answerable. The canonical duplicate for these kinds of “I've inherited a complicated project, what do?” style questions would be [I've inherited 200K lines of spaghetti code -- what now?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/155488)

Comment: @amon I see absolutely no indication that the OPs project is complex or lengthy.  This appears to be about managing a team that's chosen a language you don't know well.

Answer (score 2):

For me, there are two issues making this question difficult to answer, if not outright impossible:

1. What do you mean by "managing a project?" On the surface, this could be interpreted as literally project management — as some form of the word "manager" or "managerial". Alternatively, this could be interpreted as the management of technical dependencies and supporting tools. This aspect of your question is unclear to me.
2. Asking for "common wisdom" will never give you a single comprehensive answer. The term is left open to interpretation, so you are likely to get many equally correct answers. This does not fit the format of this community. Questions should have single answer, not multiple answers that can be equally correct.

Even though the question was reopened, I voted to close it as opinion-based (although I did not down-vote it). We have no objective criteria to judge what "common wisdom" means, and therefore we cannot really give you a comprehensive canonical answer.

Comment: I don't see those causing an issue with [the answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/440859/131624). The only issue I have is it doesn't actually talk about the impact of not knowing the teams language or how to mitigate that. But I don't see how that's the questions fault.